# JavaScript: Take Object Argument With Nested Objects and Arrays and Return Count of String Elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion, nested

I have the following problem:

// Create a function strCount (takes an object as argument) that will count all string values inside an object. For example:

The code below appears to work and gives the correct answer: 4 but I don't quite understand why.

```
function strCount(obj){


  var count = 0;

  for (var val in obj){
    if(typeof obj[val] === 'object'){
     count += strCount(obj[val]);
    }
      if (typeof obj[val] === 'string'){
        count++;
      }
  }
    return count;
}


strCount({
  first: "1",
  second: "2",
  third: false,
  fourth: ["anytime", 2, 3, 4, 'hello'],
  fifth:  null
  })
  //returns 4
```

Specifically, how is the function able to count elements in the nested array ('anytime' and 'hello')?

Comment: The best way to understand code is to step through it with a debugger. Then you'll be able to see the values of the variables at each point, and see the call stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strCount is first called with:

```
{
  first: "1",
  second: "2",
  third: false,
  fourth: ["anytime", 2, 3, 4, 'hello'],
  fifth:  null
}
```

Let's see what happens with each of these properties:

```
  first: "1", // it's a string, so it adds 1 to count
  second: "2", // same as before, now count is 2
  third: false, // nothing happens, as it is not a string nor an object (it's a boolean)
  fourth: ["anytime", 2, 3, 4, 'hello'] // here is where recursion happens
```

So what happens at fourth? Simple, it calls itself, this is called [Recursion](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/recursion-is-not-hard-858a48830d83). Now strCount is called with the param `["anytime", 2, 3, 4, 'hello']`, which is the same as calling:

```
    strCount(["anytime", 2, 3, 4, 'hello'])
```

Then the for goes through every element of the array.

```
   [
      "anytime", // it's a string, so it adds 1 to count
      2, // nothing happens
      3, // nothing happens
      4, // nothing happens
      'hello' // adds 1
   ]
```

This will return `2`, and it's added to the other 2 from the first run, finally it will go through:

```
fifth:  null
```

Which will add nothing to `count`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: to confirm, the recursion happens because an array [] is considered an object?  So if(typeof obj[val] === 'object') will return true?

Comment: That is correct. You can test it yourself by doing `typeof []` on Chrome DevTools.

Comment: great! thank you for your thorough explanation ... appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

The function uses recursion, which means it calls itself to figure out the nested count. Also, keep in mind that arrays are essentially objects (think of them as a special type of object).

Comment: oh I see ... are you saying the nested array is looked upon as an object and therefore goes through the recursion?

Comment: Yes, the "for in" loop will go through every element of the array.